# Object-C call C function to read a file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c

I'm working on a iPhone project and I need to call some C functions which is in a C file like myfile.c. And I can call some functions in it. But when I need to open a file in the C file. I got **bad access(gdb)**. The file I want to read has been put in the project folder and imported in the project.
Even, I cannot make a new file in C functions.
Anyone can give me a hand? Thank you very much.

Comment: Also note that you can't write to the app bundle.

Answer (score 1):

When using C functions with files in iOS, you can't do this

```
readFunction("filename.txt");
```

you have to make the path, for example a file in your bundle, to this

```
readFunction([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"txt"].UTF8String);
```

and do the same for writing, for example

```
NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.txt"];
writeFunction(filePath.UTF8String);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Loonam has said, you can't access files just by filename is iOS - you need to use -[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:] to get the full filename.

To do this from C, you'll need something like:

```
void testFunction(char* fileName) 
{
    NSString* fName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: fileName];
    NSString* fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: fName ofType: @""];

    const char* cFullPath = [fullPath cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //do something with cFullPath
}
```

Unfortunately, since you're using Objective-C functions here, you'd need to rename the file to be .m instead of .c - other than that it can be a normal C source file though!

Comment: As Chris suggests in his answer, it may be neater to keep Objective-C code out of the `.c` file, and instead pass `cFullPath` to `testFunction` directly.